# What's the proper way to implement a SVG image file in CSS?

Tags: css, svg, css-sprites, glyphicons

I have an SVG file with multiple SVGs with unique IDs.

```
<g id="tags">
...
</g>
<g id="tags2">
...
</g>
```

So far I have tried to implement this two ways with no luck. I tried setting it up with a background position.

```
.icon {
  background-image: url(/img/glyphicons_pro/glyphicons/svg/glyphicons.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.icon.tags-icon {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

And I tried just appending the ID of the SVG at the end, which didn't seem to work either.

```
.icon.tags-icon {
  background-image: url(/img/glyphicons_pro/glyphicons/svg/glyphicons.svg#tags);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
}
```

I've been searching for hours, can't seem to find the right approach to this...

Comment: Firefox and IE don't support SVG's as CSS background images AFAIK

Comment: Firefox and IE *do* support SVGs as CSS background as do pretty much all other UAs these days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [svg fragment identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) to show different areas assuming the different `<g>` elements are at different positions e.g.

```
<html>
<body>
<embed src="shapes.svg#svgView(viewBox(50,0,100,100))" style="width:100px;        height:100px" type="image/svg+xml" />
<embed src="shapes.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,200,100,100))" style="width:100px;height:100px" type="image/svg+xml"/> 
<embed src="shapes.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,400,100,100))" style="width:100px;height:100px" type="image/svg+xml"/>  
</body>
</html>
```

The above example shows embed but the idea applies equally well to background images.

Another way would be [SVG Stacks](http://simurai.com/post/20251013889/svg-stacks) which works by having all the drawings on top of each other and then just displaying the one you want to see using CSS.